# How does encryption systems encrypt strings? (More clarification in the explanation)

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, encoding

I am new to cryptography and I am trying to understand something. I searched it on the internet, though the question is a simple one, couldn't find an answer. So, please don't judge me by that. Here is my question:
When a string like "Hello World" is encrypted, do the algorithms convert this string into binary or ASCII? Are there examples where strings are encrypted by using ASCII codes? Also, if this is a file, can ASCII still be used to encrypt data?

Thank you in advance